# How to multiply matrices containing floating points in FPGA?

Tags: matrix, floating-point, verilog, simulink, hdl

I would like to ask a question about matrix multiplication in HDL. For 6 months I have been learning about FPGAs and ASIC design, but still do not have the enough experience for programming FPGAs using Verilog/VHDL. I had a quick search and found that Verily is suitable for me. Anyway, you just suppose me as a beginner and till now I only followed simple tutorials made of using Xilinx Spartan 3E-XCS1600E MicroBlaze Starter Kit, because I have it, too.

The most challenging part for me was to create matrices in Verilog. If I am able to create matrices and fill them with integers first, then I can move on the next step matrices with floating numbers. In advance, I also want to take inverse of these matrix and seems hard to me extremely.

My question is, what should I do in order to multiply matrices? Is there any tricky or easier way to do that like in C language? (I know Verilog is a HDL and we cannot think on that way). Also how can I convert my floating numbers to fixed or integer type? Then I think I can solve my problem in this way. I looked trough other questions but did not understand well. Thanks for your response and help.

Bonus Question: If I try these operations on MATLAB or Simulink, could it be easier to convert it to HDL using HDL Coder? If it is, could you guide me to do that?

Regards,

Leonardo

Comment: create matrices is easy .. in `system verilog` with multi-dimensional arrays. Multiplying them is easy ... in `c`. If there is no onboard arithmetic unit in your fpga, you would need to model at least a multiplier unit there as minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create matrices with RAM in hardware design. Actually, everything can be described as RAM:)

Of course only integer can be supported in Verilog, but we do have some method that can create and compute float numbers.

1. Define a float syntax. Suppose that we have `reg var[7:0]`, we can assume var[7:4] is the integer part and var[3:0] is the decimal part. Like `8'b0101_1001` equals 5.9 in DEC. You must limit the range of var[3:0] to 0~9!
2. IEEE 754. http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/  This standard has been widely used in many areas, but I think it will be a little difficult for you.

Deal with a matrices is nothing special, just follow what you have learned in math class.

I'm not good at English. Hope you can understand.